# Does setting an Audio object to undefined cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm currently writing an application that makes use of the HTML5 Audio API. In Chrome, IE and Firefox I've noticed I can create a Javascript audio object, set it to play a sound file, then make it undefined and the sound will still play, as per this example:

```
var a = new Audio;
a.src = 'longAudioFile.mp3';
a.play();
a = undefined;
```

As I am working with many Audio objects in a similar way, will this cause memory leaks if I set one to undefined or will the browser clean it up when it's finished playing/set to paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to spec:

> Media elements must not stop playing just because all references to them have been removed; only once a media element is in a state where no further audio could ever be played by that element may the element be garbage collected.
>
> It is possible for an element to which no explicit references exist to play audio, even if such an element is not still actively playing: for instance, it could have a current media controller that still has references and can still be unpaused, or it could be unpaused but stalled waiting for content to buffer.
>
> [Playing the Media Resource](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#playing-the-media-resource)

There are also cleanup instructions:

> <...> to release resources held by media elements when they are done playing, either by being very careful about removing all references to the element and allowing it to be garbage collected, or, even better, by removing the element's `src` attribute and any `source` element descendants, and invoking the element's `load()` method.
>
> [Best practices for authors using media elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#best-practices-for-authors-using-media-elements)

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know The browser will clean it up when it's finished playing.